# Java - calling methods of an object that is in ArrayList

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I have a class  **Kostka** , that has its own width (w), height (h), x and y positions for drawing it later on a JPanel using this method

```
void maluj(Graphics g) {
    g.drawRect(x, y, w, h);
}
```

Now I need to make more of them and add them in ArrayList .. then call the `maluj(g)` method for each of the **Kostka** object stored in the ArrayList

---

So far I've managed to make a method that stores the Kostka objects in ArrayList, **but I dont know how to call their methods**

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    ArrayList kos = new ArrayList(5);

    void addKostka() {
        kos.add(new Kostka(20,20,20,20));
    }

    public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
}
```

Comment: First off, you should be using Generics. Second, you should read the tutorial on using Collections and Lists if you don't understand how they work - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Invoking Methods

That's done the normal way:

```
// where kostka is an instance of the Kostka type
kostka.whateverMethodYouWant();
```

However, the way to retrieve the `kostka` from your list will depend on how you declared the list.

### Using the Good Ol' Way (Pre-Java 1.5 Style)

```
// where index is the position of the the element you want in the list
Kostka kostka = (Kotska) kos.get(index);
```

### Using Generics (The Better Way)

```
ArrayList<Kostka> kos = new ArrayList<Kostka>(5);

Kostka kostka = kos.get(index);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can perform a "cast" in order to retrieve the Kostka elements of the ArrayList:

```
for (int i = 0; i < kos.size(); i++) {
    Kostka kostka = (Kotska)kos.get(i);
    kostka.maluj(g);
}
```

If you are using a version of Java which supports Generics, the cast is unnecessary. You can do:

```
ArrayList<Kostka> kos = new ArrayList<Kostka>(5);

for (int i = 0; i < kos.size(); i++) {
    Kostka kostka = kos.get(i);
    kostka.maluj(g);
}
```